# Designing Lock Screen

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu

I use Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I want to redesign my lock screen, change orientation and stuff. Where do I find the css files for that? Or if it is not in css format, where can I find the offending files?

Answer (score 1):

https://vitux.com/how-to-change-login-lock-screen-background-in-ubuntu/ shows where the .CSS files are, which you edit with

```
$ sudo gedit /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css
```

Search for ***lockDialog*** with [**Ctrl-D**] then customize these lines to your satisfaction:

```
#lockDialogGroup {  
background: #2c001e url(file:///[fileLocation/filename.png]);  
background-repeat: no-repeat;  
background-size: cover;  
background-position: center;  
}
```